# Oracle DATE - Check if date is IN a set of years

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an employee table and I want to count the number of employees that were hired on certain years. E.g 2010, 2013, 2014 and 2016..

So far I have something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE hire_date IN(2010, 2013, 2014, 2016);
```

Comment: "How do I extract the year from a date in Oracle?" ... ?

Comment: What's any of this got to do with SYSDATE?

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, fixed it!..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I got it..

All I had to do was to extract a year from hire_date.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   employees
WHERE  extract(YEAR FROM hire_date) IN (2003, 2004, 2006, 2008);
```